# Use switch cases in an if statement

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Can we use a condition to include cases in a switch statement?

My code:

```cpp
switch(menu_option)
{
  if (g_logged_in)
  {
     case 'L':
       cout << "Login Menu\n";
       break;
     case 'S':
       cout << "Signup Menu\n";
       break;
  }
  case 'A':
    foo();
    break;
  case 'B':
    bar();
    break;

  default:
    cout << "Invalid Option!\n";
}
```

When I compile the file, I get an error

```sh
[pewpew@Sierra cpp-something]$ c++ src/main.cc -o main.out
src/main.cc: In function 'int main()':
src/main.cc:53:13: warning: statement will never be executed [-Wswitch-unreachable]
   53 |             if (g_logged_in)
      |             ^~
```

Is it not at all possible?

Comment: As the warning says: these statements won't ever be executed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hence the question, not possible by any means? Should I just include the if statement INSIDE the case?

Comment: _"not possible by any means?"_ Well, define _possible_ please. At least the code compiles, but won't do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, program control never reaches `if (g_logged_in)`, so that's never evaluated. Your helpful compiler is issuing a warning.

Really though a `switch` block is little more than a controlled set of `goto` statements. You could force it with

```
switch(menu_option){
    foo:
    if (g_logged_in){
```

with a `goto foo;` somewhere where program control reaches, although such an idea is ill-advised due to readability and maintainability. The following snippet is a reformulation of the "Hello World!" program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    switch (1){
    foo:
    if (true){
        case 0:
            std::cout << " World!\n";
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Hello";
            goto foo;
        }
    }   
}
```

For a real-life use-case for interleaved control loops within a `switch` block, see Duff's Device: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

Comment: Ah thanks, this seems to answer my question, I've looked into Duff's device but i'm fairly new to C++ so couldn't understand it much.

Comment: @RaahimFareed: It took me a few days of mental fog before Duff's Device revealed itself to me.

Comment: @RaahimFareed Modern optimizers choke to death on Duff's device, so it often isn't even useful where it's designed to be. It is also arcane code. In short, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Notice that the `if` doesn't really protect the cases, as changing `true` to `false` still prints `"Hello"` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39a559d717eff0f7).

Answer (score 2):

there is no "case" above your code.
You can't do this. The case is most likely compiled into a CPU instruction, that only works on integers.
You must use the case and do the if() twice for both cases.

Comment: I was currently using that way since the code in the question was not executing

Comment: `The case is most likely compiled into a CPU instruction` no, case is just a (special) label and is in no way related to an instruction as they're completely different things. A case label may be jump into by various ways but most of the time it isn't a single jump instruction

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify `case` statements conditionally.  You would have to do something more like this:

```cpp
switch (menu_option)
{
  case 'L':
    // in C++17 and later, you can uncomment the following
    // attribute to avoid a compiler warning...
    //
    // [[fallthrough]];
  case 'S':
    if (g_logged_in)
    {
      if (menu_option == 'L')
        cout << "Login Menu\n";
      else
        cout << "Signup Menu\n";
    }
    else
      cout << "Invalid Option!\n";
    break;

  case 'A':
    foo();
    break;

  case 'B':
    bar();
    break;

  default:
    cout << "Invalid Option!\n";
    break;
}
```

Or this:

```cpp
switch (menu_option)
{
  case 'A':
    foo();
    break;

  case 'B':
    bar();
    break;

  default:
    if (g_logged_in)
    {
      if (menu_option == 'L')
      {
        cout << "Login Menu\n";
        break;
      }
      if (menu_option == 'S')
      {
        cout << "Signup Menu\n";
        break;
      }
    }
    cout << "Invalid Option!\n";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow I never thought of doing it these ways, neat